# Antiderivative of $e^{2\arctan{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, indefinite-integrals

Is there any way to integrate this:

$$\int e^{2\arctan x}\, dx$$

I tried to solve it using integration by parts but I could not end the integral because it got very difficult.

Then I tried to solve it using Mathematica but it returned a really weird expression.

The expression is part of solving this equation

$$ y' + \frac{y}{1+x^2}=e^{\arctan x}\ $$

$$ V = e^{-\int f(x) dx} = e^{-\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2}} = e^{-\arctan x}$$
$$R = e^{\arctan x} $$

$$U = \int \frac{e^{\arctan x}}{ e^{-\arctan x}} dx$$

$$ U = \int e^{2\arctan x} dx $$

Comment: What section of the book is this question?

Comment: Since you are using an integrating factor, why don't you write out the solution for $y$ in terms of that integral. I think that you will see that even though the answer is non-elementary that it is still what any student would consider "an answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a way to proceed, we can make use of the Taylor expansion of the arctangent function:

$$\arctan(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\ x^{2k+1}$$

Hence you get:

$$\int e^{2\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\ x^{2k+1}\right)}\ \text{d}x$$

Now we use the well known symbolic property:

$$e^{\sum X} = \prod e^X$$

So we obtain:

$$\int\prod_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\ e^{\frac{2 (-1)^k}{2k+1}\ x^{2k+1}}\ \text{d}x$$

It doesn't seem very suitable right? But then let's light the writing by recalling

$$\frac{2(-1)^k}{2k+1}  = A(k) ~~~~~~~ 2k+1 = B$$

Now we have:

$$\int\prod_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\ e^{A(k)\ x^B}\ \text{d}x$$

Using the Taylor expansion for the exponential we get:

$$\prod_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\int \sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(A(k)\ x^B)^j}{j!}\ \text{d}x = \prod_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty}\frac{A^j(k)}{j!}\int x^{Bj}\ \text{d}x$$

Which is evaluable and you eventually get a solution in terms of a productory of a summatory:

$$ \prod_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{A^j(k)}{j! (Bj + 1)}\ x^{Bj + 1}$$

Comment: That Taylor series is valid only on a small interval around $0$, I believe it to be $[-1,1]$. What if the OP works outside of it? Also, who guarantees that $e^{\sum X} = \prod e^X$ is valid for series, and not just for sums? Finally, who guarantees that $\int$ and $\prod$ may be interchanged? Don't feel encouraged that the OP has accepted your answer, this only proves the he himself does not understand much of these essential subtleties.

Comment: @AlexM. I believe you shall study more calculus. Try to compute the productory of the summation, and what you will get is

$$\left(\frac{2}{5}+\frac{i}{5}\right) e^{(1+2 i) \tan ^{-1}(x)} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{i}{2};2-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)-i e^{\tan ^{-1}(x)} \, _2F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2},1;1-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)+x e^{\tan ^{-1}(x)}$$

I'm sorry if you aren't able to prove it. I did, I only avoided to write the long tedious process on the answer, since the OP already used Mathematica. My solution is the "raw" form, let's say.

Comment: I alse compute in mathematica the productory of the summation and get the answer mathematica compute at first, so @Fourier Transform, is the right answer, and thanks so much, I'm learning calculus but I did understand the answer

Comment: Sorry I meant to write 

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{(2+2 i) \tan ^{-1}(x)} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-i;2-i;-e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)-i e^{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)} \, _2F_1\left(-i,1;1-i;-e^{2 i \tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)+x e^{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}$$

(My answer still holds, I just forgot the $2$ factor in Mathematica)

Comment: How did the $\prod$ crossed the sign $\int$

Comment: @GuyFsone Absolute convergence.

Answer (score 2):

The "really weird expression" is one involving [Gaussian hypergeometric functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), which means that there is no way of representing this antiderivative by elementary functions only. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BE%5E(2%20ArcTan%5Bx%5D),%20x%5D) is the result.

Comment: well, thanks so my book is wrong

Comment: @user2461687 Seems that way. What result did it give?

Comment: its part of a linear equation

Comment: While there's not a nice answer for the integrand with $\arctan x$, there is a simple result if it's instead $\text{arctanh x}$. (You can easily modify the WA command to check this.) So you might compare the result you'd get with arctanh to what the book obtains.

Comment: thanks so much, I change the sign of the second term and got the book's result